# Booting python into startup

Tags: python-3.x, startup

I'm trying to find a way to automatically start my executable every time I boot windows. Yet I haven't found a good way to do so.

```
import fileinput
import shutil
import os

path_finder = os.path.exists(r'C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\program.exe')

if path_finder == True:
    print('file already exists in given folder. Therefore we will not proceed copying')
else:
    shutil.copyfile('program.exe','C:\\Users\\Bob\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\program.exe')
    print('Duplicate made succesfully...')
    
shutil.copyfile("program.exe","C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\program.exe")
```

I made a program that would copy itself into the startup folder. The only problem is that, depending on what computer you're on, the startup folder has a different path because of the username, for example C:\Users\bob\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup, on one computer, and on another it might be C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup.

I don't know how to make it work for every computer. If anyone has dealt with this problem before, please let me know.

Comment: Why not determine the user's folder before copying?

Comment: But how, would I do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27127710/find-startup-folder-in-windows-8-using-python could help

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSSM (https://nssm.cc/download) to setup your script into windows service. That way it can run during windows startup.